# Javascript input field placeholder alternative

Tags: javascript, html, input, placeholder

I need a replacement for the `<input placeholder="something" />` tag.
Since I cannot style this placeholder the way I want and contrast is way out of bounds for this tag.

I am not sure how to realise this other than writing a complete script to do this.
Of course if I have to. No problems. No lazyness involved. But the fact is. I'd like to keep the code fast and elegant.

I have seen a piece of code where I saw something like:

```
<input onblur="if($(this).input == '') $(this).text('default text');" onfocus="if($(this).text() == 'default text') $(this).text('')">
```

This is of course far from how it should be. But I guess you understand what I mean.
If you are on-focus the default text should be gone. And on blur if no input. The default text should be shown.

Suggested is that I can use the ::placeholder pseudo class to style it.
However under FireFox and Chrome these fail to work.

After a lot of searching online I found out that this selector doesn't always work as planned.

[image]

And my CSS :

[image]

That's why I am grabbing back to this legacy solution.

Comment: What is your question? Code like that was indeed common before `placeholder`. Are you looking for a widget that automates this and allows styling it? LIbrary requests are off-topic here.

Comment: "This is of course far from how it should be." Why?

Comment: This is far from how it should be because it isn't working ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use this CSS Selector to modify placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
text-size:3;
color:blue;
}

::placeholder {
text-size:3;
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I would use this solution (as a matter of fact I have used this "soluion") however FireFox and Chrome both ignore them. And set a certain opacity to them.